# Problems redirecting to dynamic URLs in Flask with 'action'

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

My app has a text box and a submission button. I am trying to create and redirect to dynamic URLs in my app, that are based off of what is typed in the text box. For example, the user enters in '1234', clicks submit, then is taken to 'website.com/results/1234'. The problem seems to be that the HTML for my button doesn't want to redirect the user to the new, dynamic URL. I am passing this to the HTML with Jinja.

Here is what I have.

The user starts on the home page, that is defined like this

```
@app.route("/home/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def start():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")
```

Dashboard.html has a text box and submission button (below). As you can see, the `action` of this button is to redirect to `{{ results_page }}`, where "results_page" comes from my Python function `load_results` (also below) and is passed to the HTML with `render_template`.

```
<div>
<form action="{{ results_page }}" class="form-inline" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PubmedID">Pubmed ID(s)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PubmedID" placeholder="18952863, 18269575" name="pmid" value="{{request.form.pmid}}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id= "myButton" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

The results page of my app uses the user input to look up some information and display it.

```
@app.route('/results/<query>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_results(query):
    form = pmidForm(secret_key='super secret key')
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            query = form.pmid.data #This is the user input 

            results_page = "website.com/results/"+query
            return(query)

            #do lots of stuff using the query

        return render_template('results.html', form=form, results_page = results_page)


    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

If I run my app like this, the home page is fine, but when I click "Submit", the app doesn't take in the user input or do anything with it. Simply the `home` page refreshes.

I am new to web development, but since this code works fine if I hardcode the button to `action = "website.com/results"` in the HTML, AND do without the `<query>` in `/results/<query>` for the results page, I think that only a few adjustments should be needed to make my app dynamically redirect to and load pages correctly. Right now, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Please let me know where I'm going stray.

EDIT -

Now I have implemented a `handle_form` function that redirects to my dynamic URL. This function properly redirects but then I get a 404 error.

```
@app.route('/form/', methods=["POST"]) #handles form submission
def handle_form():
    form = pmidForm(secret_key='super secret key')
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.form['pmid']
    return redirect('/results/'+query)
```

I have also edited my form in the HTML `action` to go to `/form/`

```
<form action="website.com/form/" class="form-inline" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PubmedID">Pubmed ID(s)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PubmedID" placeholder="18952863, 18269575" name="pmid" value="{{request.form.pmid}}">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id= "myButton" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
</form>
```

With this, my site will properly redirect to `/results/<query>`/ (e.g. /results/1234) but I get a 404 error. Here is how I have changed my `load_results`

```
@app.route('/results/<query>', methods=["GET"])
def load_results(query):
    form = pmidForm(secret_key='super secret key')
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            query = form.pmid.data #THIS IS THE USER INPUT FROM THE FORM #referencing 'class pmidForm'
            return query

            .
            .
            #do stuff
```

I think I am very close but need to figure out why I am getting a 404 error. My guess is that I am using "GET" incorrectly. My form in the HTML uses `method="post"`. Since this does not match with "GET", is there no way for my `load_results(query)` function to retrieve the contents of the form?

EDIT 2 -

Changed `handle_form` to redirect with `url_for`:

```
@app.route('/form/', methods=["POST"]) #handles form submission
def handle_form():
    form = pmidForm(secret_key='super secret key')
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.form['pmid']
    return redirect(url_for('.load_results', query=query))
```

And changed `load_results` to not return "query"

```
@app.route('/results/<query>', methods=["GET"])
def load_results(query):
    form = pmidForm(secret_key='super secret key')
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
             query = form.pmid.data # This shouldn't work??
             . 
             .
             # do stuff with the variable "query"
```

With this, it's still returning the 404 Error as before. Should I not be using `if request.method == GET` ?

Edit 3 -

Even a very simplified `load_results` will give me the 404 error, so I'm not sure what's up.

```
@app.route('/results/<query>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def load_results(query):
    q = query
    return render_template('test.html', q=q)
```

EDIT - 3

It seems that the accepted solution IS the correct solution to this problem, however there is an issue with uwsgi in my server that is re-directing it to the wrong location :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your punctual problem is that /home route function also needs to put the results_page url on the templating context.

```
results_page = "website.com/results"
return render_template("dashboard.html", results_page=results_page)
```

Since the variable is undefined, flask is calling the original endpoint on the form submission.

Your larger problem is that your appraoch isn't going to get you a dynamic results url that looks like /results/1234.

Typical approaches are to redirect on the server side when you handle the post request; or to use JavaScript in the client to get the form data and change the browser location to  /results/1234.

A simplified version of how to handle this with a server side redirect might look something like this.  One route that handles the form submission and another that displays results. You simply redirect from one to the other to get the nice url.

```
@app.route('/form', methods=["POST"])
def handle_form():
   query = form.pmid.data #This is the user input 
   return redirect(url_for('.load_results', query=query))

@app.route('/results/<query>') *removed the method spec to handle the redirect?
def load_results(query):
    .
    .
    # do something with query
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thanks for you reply! I understand why it isn't redirecting now. I don't exactly understand how to "redirect when you handle the post". Isn't that I'm I'm doing now? I'm not actually displaying the form again, and I ultimately do need something like /results/1234, so I need to figure out how to do this. I posted simplified code here to simply illustrate my problem. My code actually creates data visualizations :) Maybe JavaScript is the best option here? What do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for this example code! I think I am close, but not quite there. I will edit my post to show what I have now. The `handle_form` function works great to redirect, but then I get a 404 "Not Found The requested URL /results/1234 was not found on this server." Its strange that I get the default 404 and not the custom 404 error that I made. I suspect that I am using "GET" incorrectly?

Comment: You just don't have the redirect right.  My example was simplified. see my change above using the url_for method which should be foolproof.

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect how you have it (see under "Edit 2"), but it still responds with a 404 Error. Is there a problem with my `if request.method == 'GET'`? Also, will I still be able to use the variable "query" in the `load_results` function? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: could be that :)  and yes the variable gets passed along.  I took out the method spec from the route. Take out the if too!

Comment: Now I'm really not sure what the problem is because I commented everything out in `load_results` and just wrote `q=query` and `return render_template('test.html', q=q)` and tried to print the query (as "q") in the HTML body via Jinja, and still got the 404, just as before. The URL that it is forwarding to looks just how I want it to, but I'm not sure what's happening here?? Not sure what to investigate next. Ideas?

Comment: just hit the url /results/6666  in the browser and see what happend.

Comment: Ah, I think i figured it out?! When it is returning `return redirect(url_for('.load_results', query=query))` it is not appending the `/results/<query>` to the correct location. Its cutting off the rest of the path. (e.g. it should be website.com/project/results/1234, but instead it goes to website.com/results/1234). I should have seen this sooner but I wasn't looking at the full link. Any idea on this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120551/discussion-between-robert-moskal-and-snarkshark).

Comment: OK. I'm in the chat :) Thank you!